# How to sort multiple lists while using datetime

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, datetime

I need to sort app reviews in my csv file by date to later use to make scatter graphs using matplotlib.

My current code is:

```
def example():
    date = []
    positive = []
    negative = []
    ratings = []
    for row in app_data:
        date.append(row[0])
        positive.append(row[3])
        negative.append(row[2])
        ratings.append(row[4])
    final = sorted(zip(date, negative, positive, ratings), reverse=True)
    final.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y"))
    print(final)    `
```

The problem is I can only sort the dates into the right order using datetime but I need all the lists to be in the same order as to not mix up the reviews.

There is extra data in my csv file after the columns i've read in if that impacts the answer at all.

It might also be worth mentioning that some reviews have the same date too.

an example of my data would be:

```
DATE,NAME,NEGATIVE REVIEW,POSITIVE REVIEW,RATING GIVEN
03/10/2005,teams,No Negative, very easy to use,8
03/10/2005,skype,i hate this app, No Positive,2.5
12/26/2005,skype,hard to navigate initially, easy to use once you learn the layout,6
07/10/2006,instagram,this app ruined my life,No Positive,1.5
```

thank you.

Comment: Would the problem be easier if you did the sorting *before* you split everything up into four separate lists?  Does splitting everything up into four separate lists actually make anything else easier?

Comment: You can use something like Pandas or Numpy to store your data as a table and sort based on whatever you want. This way everything will change place with the sorted item.

Comment: can you provide a sample of your data so we can work on it?

Comment: an example of my data would be:

DATE, NAME ,NEGATIVE REVIEW, POSITIVE REVIEW, RATING GIVEN
03/10/2005,teams,No Negative, very easy to use,8
03/10/2005,skype,i hate this app, No Positive,2.5
12/26/2005,skype,hard to navigate initially, easy to use once you learn the layout,6
07/10/2006,instagram,this app ruined my life,No Positive,1.5

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
import pandas as pd
rows = [['02/04/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['01/01/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['04/04/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'good','bad', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'very Good','not good', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'Best','not good', 4.2],]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
#use df.sort_values(column) for single column and use list of columns name for sorting on multiple columns
#0 and 1 are columns name
df = df.sort_values([0,1,2])
```

If you want to sort your data on multiple columns, the second column will work only if there is repetition in the first column. In the above code, everything will be sorted on `column 0`, If the values are the same in the `column 0`, then `column 1` will sort the values. If the values are the same in both `column 0 and 1`, then `column 2` will work.

**EDIT**
this will work for your data as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` module to make comparison along dates. `datetime.strptime` converts string data to a datetime object. For sorting something by another operation, there is a parameter called `key`. Here is a simple way to do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
data = [['02/04/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['01/01/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['04/04/2022', 'good','not good', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'good','bad', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'very Good','not good', 4.2],
        ['02/03/2022', 'Best','not good', 4.2],]
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0],"%d/%m/%Y"))
print(*sorted_data,sep="\n")
```

Also you can change date format by changing this part:

> "%d/%m/%Y"